# CosmosDB Table API - CORS rules are not supported for this API

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-tables

We have some Azure Table storage tables in our subscription and would like to migrate them to CosmosDB table API due to performance reasons. To do this, I started creating cosmos db account by selecting Table API but my deployment failed with the following error. When i tried with SQL API, it works.

{"code":"DeploymentFailed","message":"At least one resource deployment operation failed. Please list deployment operations for details. "details":[{"code":"BadRequest","message":"{\r\n \"code\": \"BadRequest\",\r\n \"message\": \"**CORS rules are not supported for this API**\rMicrosoft.Azure.Documents.Common/2.1.0.0\"\r\n}"}]}

Can someone please let me know what could be the reason for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@AngiSen, may be related to a recent (breaking) update of Azure Cosmos DB resource provider ([Microsoft.DocumentDb/databaseAccounts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.documentdb/2015-04-08/databaseaccounts)) as I just noticed today (28th of Nov 2018) that a previously running deployment (as of 23th of Nov 2018) of Cosmos DB Table API is now failing with this same error:

`9:16:23 AM - Resource Microsoft.DocumentDb/databaseAccounts 'xxx-xxx-xxx' failed with message '{
  "code": "BadRequest",
  "message": "CORS rules are not supported for this API\r\nActivityId: xxx, Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Common/2.1.0.0"
}'`

In my case I'm using **2015-04-08** version with Table API but I don't configure explicitly the CORS part and anyway there's no such configuration option in the resource provider.

Digging into the existing Cosmos DB instance with https://resources.azure.com shows there's indeed a CORS member that is part of the definition:

`{
  "id": "/subscriptions/xxx/resourceGroups/xxx/providers/Microsoft.DocumentDB/databaseAccounts/xxx",
  "name": "xxx",
  "location": "North Europe",
  "type": "Microsoft.DocumentDB/databaseAccounts",
  "kind": "GlobalDocumentDB",
  "tags": {},
  "properties": {
    "provisioningState": "Succeeded",
    "documentEndpoint": "https://xxx.documents.azure.com:443/",
    "tableEndpoint": "https://xxx.table.cosmosdb.azure.com:443/",
    "ipRangeFilter": "",
    "enableAutomaticFailover": false,
    "enableMultipleWriteLocations": false,
    "isVirtualNetworkFilterEnabled": false,
    "virtualNetworkRules": [],
    "EnabledApiTypes": "Table, Sql",
    "databaseAccountOfferType": "Standard",
    "consistencyPolicy": {
      "defaultConsistencyLevel": "BoundedStaleness",
      "maxIntervalInSeconds": 86400,
      "maxStalenessPrefix": 1000000
    },
    "configurationOverrides": {},
    "writeLocations": [
      {
        "id": "xxx-northeurope",
        "locationName": "North Europe",
        "documentEndpoint": "https://xxx-northeurope.documents.azure.com:443/",
        "provisioningState": "Succeeded",
        "failoverPriority": 0
      }
    ],
    "readLocations": [
      {
        "id": "xxx-northeurope",
        "locationName": "North Europe",
        "documentEndpoint": "https://xxx-northeurope.documents.azure.com:443/",
        "provisioningState": "Succeeded",
        "failoverPriority": 0
      }
    ],
    "locations": [
      {
        "id": "xxx-northeurope",
        "locationName": "North Europe",
        "documentEndpoint": "https://xxx-northeurope.documents.azure.com:443/",
        "provisioningState": "Succeeded",
        "failoverPriority": 0
      }
    ],
    "failoverPolicies": [
      {
        "id": "xxx-northeurope",
        "locationName": "North Europe",
        "failoverPriority": 0
      }
    ],
    "cors": [],
    "capabilities": [
      {
        "name": "EnableTable"
      }
    ]
  }
}`

Hope it'll get fixed quickly if it's indeed a breaking change...

Comment: I am bringing this to the attention of the Cosmos DB product group. I will have an update shortly.

Answer (score 1):

Wanted to make an official statement here. I have spoken with the Cosmos DB team and they have a fix ready and it should be deployed tonight. Please let me know if you should have any questions. Thank you for posting the issue.

Comment: Yes.. i got an update from MSFT that it will be fixed today..thanks